# AX2012 Sales Order Creation through AX Classes

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to create a sales order in ax 2012 through x++ code, I searched for it and only found direct header and line creation through creating and inserting table buffers, I want to create sales order through standard AX Class so I dont have to worry for business rules. Like we can create transfer order with AxInventTransferTable and AxinventTransferLine classes.

A simple code example would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at a blog post of a colleague of mine. He has written a post about the SalesAutoCreate framework.

[Creating sales order with SalesAutoCreate](http://www.kevinroos.be/2010/07/salesautocreate-class/)

It explains nicely how you can extend this framework to add a custom type of sales order import. Also the SalesAutoCreate already contains some business logic for general SalesTable and SalesLine fields.

PS: Another option would be to use the SalesSalesOrderService class and AxSalesTable / AxSalesLine classes. (The equivalent of the AxBc classes you use for your transfer orders)